# How to realize the FFT/IFFT with complex numbers

Tags: ios, fft, complex-numbers, ifft, vdsp

I have seen many examples of vDSP that realize the FFT / IFFT with real numbers but I have not seen any event that realizes the FFT / IFFT with complex numbers.
Can you indicate the direction I should take?
Thank's you in advance.

Comment: See [Note on Strides](https://developer.apple.com/reference/accelerate/vdsp).

Comment: Sorry but i can't find a example for vDSP_fft_zip.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/accelerate/1450150-vdsp_fft_zrip

Comment: A complex number is just 2 real numbers that you (or the FFT code) decide to multiply using complex arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this:

https://github.com/mattt/Surge/blob/master/Source/FFT.swift

Hope it helps you.